# Integral involving CDF of a standard normal random variable

Tags: integration, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $\Phi(\cdot)$ be the CDF of a standard normal random variable $Z \sim N(0,1)$. Define a function

$$
F(x) = \int_{-\ln (x)}^{x^2} \Phi(t+x) dt.
$$

Question: what is $F'(1)$, where $F'(x)$ is the first derivative of $F$?

Now I have broken the integral in two pieces as follows

$$
F(x) = -\int_{0}^{\ln x} \Phi(t+x) dt + \int_{0}^{x^2} \Phi(t+x) dt
$$

and want to differentiate both integrals according with the formula

$$
G(x) = \int_0^{\phi(x)} h(x,y) dy \Rightarrow G'(x) = \int_0^{\phi(x)} h_x(x,y) dy +h(x, \phi(x))\phi(x)'.
$$

However, at this point I am not sure how to appy this formula. Indeed, if I want to use it to determine for example the first integral

$$
(-\int_{0}^{\ln x} \Phi(t+x) dt)'
$$

I am forced to compute

$$
\int_{0}^{\ln x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Phi(t+x) dt 
$$

and I am stuck here. How is this integral to be done?

Comment: The easiest thing here is to notice that $\partial_x \Phi(t + x) = \partial_t\Phi(t + x)$, and then $\int \partial_x \Phi(t + x) dx$ should be much easier to compute.

Comment: Hint: Apply your general formula to $$F(x) = \int_{x-\ln x}^{x+x^2} \Phi(t) dt
$$ hence $$F'(x)=(1+2x)\Phi(x+x^2)-\left(1-\frac1x\right)\Phi(x-\ln x)$$

Comment: @Did thanks, useful comment.